# How to prevent daily index fragmentation of 99%

Tags: sql-server-2008, index, fragmentation

I have a highscore table for 100.000 players that is being inserted into 2 times a day with one record per player. At the end of the day the index fragmentation for the indexes in that table is 99%. Is there a way to prevent this by tweaking the settings?

```
CREATE TABLE HighScore(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user] [int] NULL,
    [player] [int] NULL,
    [round] [tinyint] NULL,
    [group] [int] NULL,
    [rank] [int] NULL,
    [delta] [int] NULL,
    [roundpoints] [int] NULL,
    [totalpoints] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [HighScore_RoundGroup_Nidx] ON .[HighScore] 
(
    [round] ASC,
    [group] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Silly question, but to cover all basis - are you rebuilding/reorganizing every day?

Comment: without TABLE DDL anyone posting will guess. Are you using GUID as primary key?

Comment: I am rebuilding every day right now but I wonder if I can prevent this from having to happen every day since I can anticipate pretty well on how the data evolves.

Comment: How are you determining fragmentation level? I wouldn't expect much logical fragmentation at all for the clustered index. Some internal fragmentation though, you don't need `FILLFACTOR = 80` there. It will just waste space. All the columns are fixed length so a row can't expand on update and inserts can't happen in the middle of the table. 99% seems unexpectedly high for the other index too. How many pages are there in each index?

Comment: 99% after rebuilding each day would really be going some, can you show your `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` output?

Comment: I know this sounds like a totally off the wall couple of questions but are you using SQL Server 2016 or earlier and are you also using the WITH (ONLINE = ON) option during the index rebuild?  Check the fragmentation on your index right after you do the rebuilds.  If the indexes are highly fragmented right after the REBUILDs, try using WITH (ONLINE = OFF).  There's a bug in ONLINE = ON in 2016 that no one yet seems to know about.  It appears to have been fixed in 2017.  I don't know about other versions but check.  From the looks of your clustered index, it should NEVER become fragmented.

Comment: Heh... and just now I also realize I just necro'd an 8 year old post. Maybe my comment above will still help someone.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try higher `FILLFACTOR` settings on `HighScore_RoundGroup_Nidx` (e.g. 50 or 40). You can set `FILLFACTOR` to 0 or 100 for the `PRIMARY KEY` because it shouldn't fragment If it still does, `FILLFACTOR` does not help because the reason is that newly allocated pages interleave with other newly allocated pages. This is a well-known SQL Server issue. You could move this index into its own filegroup which would stop this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you think you are rebuilding but the index doesn't get rebuilt because the index isn't large enough.

Have a look at this question
[Why index REBUILD does not reduce index fragmentatation?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18372/why-index-rebuild-does-not-reduce-index-fragmentatation)

Did you check the fragmentation after rebuild? Is it actually defragmented.