# Index Maintenance on SQL Server 2008 R2 Web edition

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, index-tuning

I've inherited of a couple of databases which indexes have never been maintained (rebuilt, reorganized).

I'm using Ola Hallengren's [Index maintenance script](http://ola.hallengren.com/), I've used the following script to record the difference between the pre-maintenance and post-maintenance values.

Script :

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(IPS.object_id) AS [TableName] ,
    SI.name AS [IndexName] ,
    IPS.Index_type_desc ,
    IPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent ,
    IPS.avg_fragment_size_in_pages ,
    IPS.avg_page_space_used_in_percent ,
    IPS.record_count ,
    IPS.ghost_record_count ,
    IPS.fragment_count 
   -- ,IPS.avg_fragment_size_in_pages
FROM    
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(N'test_db'), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') IPS
JOIN 
    sys.tables ST WITH (NOLOCK) ON IPS.object_id = ST.object_id
JOIN 
    sys.indexes SI WITH (NOLOCK) ON IPS.object_id = SI.object_id
                                 AND IPS.index_id = SI.index_id
WHERE   
    ST.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY 
    3 Desc, 4 Desc
```

However, I didn't notice any changes on the various indexes having an `avg_fragmentation_in_percent` above 30%.

Are index maintenance tasks supported on SQL Server 2008R2 Web Editions?

Comment: I believe you're bumping up against [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18372/why-index-rebuild-does-not-reduce-index-fragmentatation).

Comment: Thanks  it really help understanding the issue, another [ressource](http://http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5365/why-is-my-database-still-fragmented-after-i-rebuilt-and-reindexed-everything/) -

Answer (score 0):

For small tables (typically reduced pages count), fragmentation cannot be avoided due to how sql server handles extents.

More info : http://www.practicalsqldba.com/2012/04/sql-server-measuring-index.html